# Getter and setters in Kotlin using Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and working on getters and setters. I am making one data class where I am setting my String values. I have 2 Activities, from ActivityA I am setting a data and I want to get it in other ActivityB. How can I get data from my data Class in my ActivityB?

My code snippet is given below:

data class HelperMethods:

```
data class HelperMethods(val name: String, val publisher: String)
```

ActivityA where I am setting data:

```
val userName = HelperMethods("abc","efg")
```

I want to get this data from my data class in my ActivityB.

Comment: you can use intent

Comment: you're not setting data. You're creating an instance

Comment: Does B already have a reference to A?

Comment: @s1m0nw1 thanks for your reply here. I need to set data from ActivityA and to get Data in ActivityB. This all I need but without bundle, I want it through Getter/Setters. Can you please help me with code snippet.

Comment: @TimCastelijns thanks for your reply. Can you please help me with your code snippet. I need to set Data from 1 Activity and to get the data from another Activity.

Comment: @sanemars thanks for your reply here. I want to do it without setting intent. I want to do it through Getter/Setter.

Comment: You basically have 2 valid options - intent extra or persistent storage (db or sharedpreferences). All others are breaking architecture and causing memory leaks

Comment: As I noted on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47161443), please-halp-me and thanks-in-advance chat is best omitted on this platform: _I notice that your questions are liberally sprinkled with pleading phrases - there was "please help me out to resolve this issue" twice in this one, now edited out. It's worth refraining from chatty stuff mainly because we like succinctness here, but it's worth noting that begging material can cause people to skip or downvote. Hope that helps!_

Answer (score 1):

Your data class should implements Serializable interface, and then pass this parameter to Intent: `intent.putExtra("name", yourSerializableObject)`.
Then, in activityB you can get this data using: `intent.getSerializableExtra("name")`. If you have some strange flow (like A -> ... -> B) then you can store your values in sharedPreferences. But, if you open B from A, just pass it as intentExtra.

Answer (score 0):

OPTION 1: Intent

OPTION 2: persistent storage DataBase / SharedPrefrence

OPTION 3: use EventBus / Rx - PublishSubject

OPTION 4:

```
var commonVariable : HelperMethods? = null
```

at file level in kotlin.

or

```
class Common{
  companion object{
   var commonVariable : HelperMethods? = null
  }
}
```

In your Activity 1 create an instance and assignee it to the variable

```
Common.commonVariable = HelperMethods("abc,efg")
```

In your Activity 2 consume it.

```
Log.d("i am consuming here",Common.commonVariable.toString)
```

You just need to handle lifecycle to VOID MEMORY LEAKS

Comment: This is a terrible idea

Comment: Intent extras is highly recommended for passing data from one activity to another.Passing data through static and preference is the worst way of doing it

Comment: Agreed. But the requirement is smthing different